# Validation Control Chaining

Tags: asp.net, validation, .net-4.0

Another "I am pretty sure I know the answer, but I'll ask anyway just in case" question.
(The answer I think being "no, there isn't")

Is there any built-in way to chain validators in ASP.NET (.Net 4.0) without the need to write `<asp:CustomValidator>` code?  So that one validator will only be checked if another validator has passed it's validation?

For instance, say you have two `<asp:DropDownList>` controls, both with the exact same options, including a "blank" entry at the start (because you don't want anything pre-selected, that is a decision the user must consciously make)...

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="dd1">
  <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text=""/>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</ListItem>
  ...
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="dd2">
  ... with identical list of items as dd1
```

I would put two `<asp:CompareValidator>` controls, one associated with each of the above `<asp:DropDownList>` controls

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" id="val1" ControlToValidate="dd1"
  ValueToCompare="-1" Operation="Not Equal" ErrorMessage="Select DD1" />
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" id="val2" ControlToValidate="dd2"
  ValueToCompare="-1" Operation="Not Equal" ErrorMessage="Select DD2" />
```

These work fine, and shows the appropriate error if the original "blank" entry is the selected item.

However, I need the two items to be different, so I add another `<asp:CompareValidator>`...

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" id="val3" ControlToValidate="dd1"
  ControlToCompare="dd2" Operation="Not Equal" ErrorMessage="DD2 must be different to DD1" />
```

The result of this is that if both `DD1` and `DD2` have the "blank" as their selected items, all three validators will fire on a form submit.  This is incorrect, as `val3` should only be validated if `val2` has successfully validated.

The obvious solution is to use a `<asp:CustomValidator>` instead, and handing the situation myself... but I thought I'd ask if there was a built-in way of making `val3` only validate if `val2` was valid.

Comment: Same unanswered question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257374/asp-net-webforms-short-circuit-validation

Comment: Thanks @plalx, I did do some searching, but I didn't think of the term "short-circuit".  The lack of answers certainly points to nothing built-in being available